# Is it possible to know what methods and properties defined in a class by decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript

suppose I have a class as below, how to write a decorator that detects class A has property `a`?

```js
@Dec
class A {
    a:string;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know this at runtime or during type-check-time? I.e. are you wanting this information for type checking?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I wish to know this at type-check-time

Comment: Are you wanting to apply the decorator to more than one class? If so, are you wanting to have type information about all those classes or just one of them at a time?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin yes i will apply the decorator to multiple classes. I want to collect the constructors of all the classes with this annotation and spit an error if any of the decorated class does not have property ```a```

Comment: To help me understand, how come you are using a decorator for that instead of having all the classes implement an interface that has the property `a`?

Comment: I am making a library and just trying to see if this is possible without  user extend class or implement interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json`, enable `experimentalDecorators`.

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

Then make the [class decorator function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) accept an interface as its constructor return type.

For example, the following will give a compiler error when `Point` does not have the `x` property.

```
@validate
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    constructor() {
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 1;
    }
}

interface HasX {
    x: number;
}

function validate(constructor: new () => HasX) { }
```

Here is the above [in the playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/AINwhgNglgJmAuBTAUAYwmAzpgBABQHsoA7eHAb2R2pwA8AuHYgVwFsAjRAJwG4qaAnoxYdufGjlQFimeF2ap4BLgAoAlBX4Tq8ABZRMAOlo4AvDgCM47Tv1GBZy9eoBfZG%20QkkXAGZhUiDgAElgAGpoSDExsnLzuyMg%20zMSKUNI44NBwSCpSMnIKSlzCiADuOOpmAHzBYRrkOC5AA).

Comment: Why not just get rid of the generic entirely? `function validate(ctor: new () => HasX)`

Comment: Good point. I was getting too fancy with all the generic and metadata stuff.